# Adding Graphics to JPanel

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a graphic onto a JPanel. I have working code for creating a rectangle and putting it onto a frame. Now for some reason when I try to add it onto a JPanel, I don't see anything. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong or the process for adding graphics to a JFrame doesn't work for adding to a JPanel.

This is the code that DOESN'T work:

Panel

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Window2 extends JFrame {
    public Window2() {
        Container panel = this.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setSize(1000,1000);

        ExampleComponent2 dc = new ExampleComponent2();
        panel.add(dc);

        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window window = new Window();
    }   
}
```

DrawingComponent class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class ExampleComponent2 extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20,20,40,40);
        g2.draw(rect1);
    }
}
```

And this is the code that DOES work:

Main Class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(650,500);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

        ExampleComponent dc = new ExampleComponent();
        window.add(dc);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @rrobby86 I think that it is preferred to override the paintComponent method. Do you have a reference that says otherwise?

Comment: ah ok, I just followed code from a tutorial i watched, i tried changing it to the paint method, but nothing changed.

Comment: So it looks like the only difference is your layout. The default layout for a JFrame content pane is a BorderLayout. What is the result you get when it "doesn't work". You have a FlowLayout, but your custom component doesn't specify a size. It just tries to draw.

Comment: I've tried a BorderLayout as well as a GridBagLayout. When I say it doesn't work I mean a blank frame appears when I run it, no graphic at all.

Comment: Try giving your ExampleComponent2 a size by either a) overriding the min/max/preferred sizes or b) calling the respective setters.

Comment: @matt: you are right, I was remembering wrong, thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExampleComponent2 dc = new ExampleComponent2();
dc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
panel.add(dc);
```

Then it shows up for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Layout.
Try the Borderlayout and after that read some API.

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: I've tried changing to BorderLayout and it didn't change anything. It was originally part of a GridBagLayout, but i just broke it down to something simpler.

Comment: Look your main: Window window = new Window(). Change to Window2 window = new Window2()